# Textbox "x" icon

Tags: user-research, usability-study

Nowadays we don't see the "x" icon in text box anymore. A user can use this icon to erase the whole text field. Does the placement of this icon depend on the kind of app? Any particular reason for removing this icon?

Comment: What are your examples of when this was a standard? Web browsers often add them automatically to 'search' type text fields - IE11 and Chrome, for example.

Answer (score 3):

the reason = users clicked on it by accident

in the rare cases users want to do it, it is really simple to select all text and press delete on a desktop

the idea might need to be revisited for mobile if someone discovers that their users want to delete the text more often than they tap on random buttons by accident

Comment: It ahold be noted that it isn't common to see the "x" on plain text fields however the scenario where where users frequently want to clear the value (Search) the "x" is still quite common. The one place where this is very tricky is on a URL/search bar in mobile browsers that swap a reload/"x" icon depending on state. I cant count the number of times I've hit it, wanting the other.